# Exprimer qu'un objet n'est pas une adaptation d'un objet existant

Tags: choix-de-mot

Je cherche une manière concise d'exprimer qu'un objet est fabriqué à partir de ses composants premiers, par opposition à l'adaptation d'un objet de même nature existant déjà. La méthode de construction de l'objet est par contre une méthode bien connue, il n'y a pas d'invention. Par exemple, il pourrait s'agir d'écrire la deuxième version d'un document en imitant peut-être la structure de l'ancien, mais pas en faisant une copie de la permière version qu'on modifierait ensuite. Ou encore, on dispose d'une chaise, et on construit une deuxième chaise qui ressemble à la première avec des planches de bois, par opposition à raboter un peu une chaise existante pour qu'elle soit conforme au modèle. Le contexte est plutôt formel.

« Nouveau » ne convient pas car on dirait naturellement qu'un objet adapté est nouveau (par rapport à l'ancien objet non adapté). J'ai pensé à « à partir de rien », mais l'expression ne me convient pas à cause de son imprécision : l'objet est fabriqué à partir de composants et à l'aide de techniques bien définis, et l'expression me semble légèrement informelle. En anglais, je dirais bien « *from scratch* » dans un contexte moins formel.

Est-ce que « *ab novo* » (utilisé comme adverbe : un objet généré *ab novo*) est compréhensible par un francophone cultivé ? Ou serait-ce plutôt « *de novo* » ? Je suis tout à fait ouvert à de meilleures propositions.

Comment: je pensais que le "from scratch" anglais se rapprochait plus du "ex nihilo"

Comment: *Ex nihilo* me vient immédiatement à l'esprit.

Comment: @Evpok J'ai ajouté un exemple, je trouve *ex nihilo* trop fort. L'objet est nouvellement fabriqué mais la méthode de fabrication n'est pas nouvelle. *Ex nihilo* suggère une nouvelle méthode, ou c'est moi qui me fait une fausse idée ?

Comment: @Gilles : _ex nihilo_ ne veut pas forcément dire avec une nouvelle méthode, mais plutôt à partir de rien (en informatique, c'est par exemple une classe qui n'hérite d'aucune autre classe).

Comment: *Ab novo*, jamais entendu parler. Je ne dirais pas que ma culture vaille réponse définitive, mais *a priori*, non, pas compréhensible (enfin sauf à ce que tu puisses motiver ton lecteur à aller chercher son Larousse). Je trouve aussi *ex nihilo* trop fort (pour moi, ça implique qu'on se passe de matériau, donc pour la chaise, c'est pas gagné).

Answer (score 4):

Je dirais "**un objet construit de toutes pièces**".

Comment: @Gilles: Merci pour les corrections.

Comment: J'utiliserais "fabriquer" plutôt que "construit", mais le sens reste le même.

Comment: Il y a un côté « réutilisation » qui me semble aller dans le sens de la question et qui m'empêche de moinsoir, parce que c'est bizarre, quand même. Pourquoi pas « reconstruit de toutes pièces » ?

Answer (score 2):

Dans un contexte commercial, c'est un "objet neuf" (par opposition à "usagé" ou "d'occasion", voire "recyclé"). Pour un document, on pourrait dire "réécrit" (ou "récrit").

Answer (score 2):

Je ne sais pas ce que ça vaut (maintenant j'y ai trop réfléchi) mais je propose au cas où:

> Un objet de nouvelle facture.

(Et qui ne serait pas forcément de facture nouvelle).

Comment: Puisque l'étymologie *facture* = *façon de faire* ? Joli.

Answer (score 2):

Ta chose me semble pouvoir être, par rapport à l'original :

- une ***refonte*** : ça va pour la chaise, on recycle le bois et on recommence, mais a l'air de sous-entendre qu'on restructure le document. Au moins, c'est assez formel.
- une version ***parallèle*** : rien d'extraordinairement novateur, le même objectif, mais pas de lien entre les deux non plus, à part peut-être un peu d'inspiration à mi-chemin. *Alternative*, éventuellement, mais j'aime moins.
- construit suivant une méthode ***revisitée*** (ou simplement l'original *revisité*, mais je crois que ça ne colle pas très bien) : ça précise que tu pars des mêmes éléments de base pour arriver à un résultat semblable, et puis que tu n'as pas pris le même chemin. Par contre, ça veut sûrement dire que tu as apporté un peu de nouveauté.
- une *reproduction par un autre biais* ?

Answer (score 0):

Quand on dit un "objet nouveau" ou une "méthode nouvelle" avec l'adjectif **"nouveau" après le nom**, je pense qu'on comprend bien que cet objet est très différent de ce qui a pu pré-exister.

Sinon, dans un "objet **original**" ou une "méthode originale" (par opposition à la copie), on comprend bien que l'objet n'est pas similaire à un autre.

Pour être plus précis, on pourrait dire, un objet **conçu à partir de zéro**, ou un objet **non-dérivé**.

Comment: Non (j'ai rajouté un exemple pour clarifier), l'objet est nouveau mais sa méthode de conception est classique.

Answer (score 0):

Dans les cas donnés en exemple, je dirais "ré-écrire le document de zéro" ou "refaire une chaise de zéro".

Comment: Comme *from scratch* et *ex nihilo*, sauf que précisément, ce n'est pas exactement de zéro si ce n'est pas *à partir de rien* (comme mentionné dans la question).

Answer (score 0):

On utilise souvent *from-scratch* parce que ça exprime bien cette notion qui n'a pas vraiment d'équivalent en français.

Cela me rappelle les notions de *dérivation*, de *spécialisation* et d'*implémentation* provenant de la Programmation Orientée Objet du monde de l'informatique. L'équivalent pour ce problème est donc l'*abstraction*, dans le cas d'un objet *générique* ou bien la *spécialisation* dans le cas d'un objet *héritant* des caractéristiques d'un autre.

Bien que ces termes soient très spécifiques, je les ai déjà entendus employés dans des contextes assez divers, comme la sociologie, la sémantique (notion de *classe*) ou l'architecture.

Comment: Les non-programmeurs te regardent avec des yeux ronds, te font confiance, mais ont du mal à voir comment refaire un objet s'appelle une *abstraction*.

Answer (score 0):

Pourquoi ne pas dire simplement « complète » ou « intégrale » ?

> une re-création complète
>
> un re-assemblage intégral

Cela semble exprimer le fait de ne pas prendre de raccourci.

Sinon « de zéro » ou « de néant » pourrait aussi marcher.

Answer (score -2):

Pourquoi pas quelque chose comme "un raffinement" ? 
On garde ici l'idée d'historique tout en apportant l'idée de quelque chose de nouveau.

Cela ne marche sans doute pas pour l'exemple de la chaise, mais peut-être du coup "un design revu et corrigé", ou encore "un concept renouvelé", seraient adaptés?

Comment: Rafinement donne pour moi l'idée inverse que celle que Gilles cherche.